¿Alguién sabe si ya cambió esta línea de regla en "analysis_options.yaml"?
¿Alguién sabe si ya cambió esta línea de regla en "analysis_options.yaml", la que estaba usando es "    prefer_const_literals_to_create_inmutables: false"?
En el framework de Flutter con DART, la versión es:version: 1.0.0+1
analysis_options.yaml

rules:
    prefer_const_constructors: false
    prefer_const_literals_to_create_inmutables: false
    

Por que me da el siguiente error:

error:'prefer_const_literals_to_create_inmutable' is not a recognized
lint rule. Try using the name of a recognized lint rul


En tu error dice inmutable, no inmutables. ¿En verdad está bien escrito?

@padaleiana seguramente lo tenía mal escrito, ahora en su respuesta es correcto pero debe generar nuevamente su proyecto.

No deberías usar prefer_const_literals_to_create_inmutable, debes usar prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, al revisar tu configuración en el archivo analysis_options.yaml es correcta:
rules:
    prefer_const_constructors: false
    prefer_const_literals_to_create_inmutables: false

Construye nuevamente tu proyecto para que funcione.
